# Why don't you do it no more?

Tags: sayings

Can I say

*Why don't you do it no more?*

in the same meaning as

*Why did you stop doing it?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many varieties of English spoken across the world. Commonly recognised variants are en-uk, en-us, en-au, en-nz, en-sa, en-in(south asian English).

There is another less commonly recognised version, which is [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English).

Your sentence

> Why don't you do it no more?

would be correct in [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English). However in almost all other variants, the following would be considered the proper sentence.

> Why don't you do it any more?

**"Why don't you do it any more?"** has the same meaning as **"Why did you stop doing it?"**

Answer (score 3):

It does have the same meaning, but in correct English we say

> Why don't you do it any more?

*Don't (do not)* and *no more* form a [double negative](https://www.niu.edu/writingtutorial/grammar/double-negatives.shtml), which is used in some dialects, but is considered wrong in standard English.